# Socket.io Cross-domain connections fail; 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load ...'

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, socket.io

I'm trying to do cross-domain socket.io, but I'm experiencing an issue:
I always get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://handsonwithnodejs.samarthwiz.c9.io/socket.io/1/?t=1358882710333. Origin https://c9.io is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Server code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

On line 19 `io.set('origins', '*:*');`I tried replacing '*:*' with '*', 'https://c9.io', '*c9.io*','https://c9.io/*' and '.', some times when I add something like 'c9.io/*'
I get warn 'illegal origin ...' but that is just a cloud9 related issue.

Client code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/master/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://handsonwithnodejs.samarthwiz.c9.io');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I know that using github to get my script isn't the best idea yet, but I wanted to keep my code clean and the error messages readable(everything in 'socket.io.min.js' is on line 2)

P.S. 1. I know that there are other threads like this but they didn't solve my problem.
     2. Please don't reply 'Just host the page on the same server as socket.io' I need                     it to be cross-domain for a reason.

Comment: It's funny, I have been trying to stop other domains using my Socket.io by messing around Origin xdomain etc. and no luck so far! I can io.connect to MyIP:Port from every where. Now you are saying you can't access from other domains. Please tell me how to stop CORS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when you host the client code. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more info about the header.

This header must be set by the client for security reasons.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? from what I see the server that hosts the file needs to set it, however according to you the client(the html file) sets it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I say client, I mean the webserver hosting the client file, I know that was not very clear, sorry. How do you host the client HTML file?

Comment: I thought there might be a JavaScript function like set('access.control', '*'), Thanks. I'm right now hosting on cloud9, once finished I will deploy to phone gap.

Comment: @Samarthwiz did you ever get around this? I have the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265742/how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-a-simple-http-request?noredirect=1#comment43002957_27265742 and I'm not sure how to set the access control in cloud9

Comment: I didn't. I gave up.